# Open database Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I need to open a database from my phone's memory (/storage/emulated/0) and I've got "SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException" the database to open (created by DB browser from linux) have the tables "android_metadata" and them respective fields (locale...es_US).

I need open and read data from the external db (the app need to download the db from website and read data and put in textview into the app activities )

The app has permission to read and write external memory

code below (only the code of button to get the database reference)

```
case R.id.button4:
            {
                int ID,IDn,IDa;
                String cabeceras[] ={"nombre","apellido",_ID},lectura=new String(),err="";
                ArrayList<String> arregloDatos = new ArrayList<>();

                try {
                    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/"+"pruebaDB.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

                    Cursor cursor = db.query("persona", cabeceras, null, null, null, null, null);


                    ID = cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID);
                    IDn = cursor.getColumnIndex("nombre");
                    IDa = cursor.getColumnIndex("apellido");

                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        lectura = cursor.getString(ID) + " " + cursor.getString(IDn) + " " + cursor.getString(IDa);
                        arregloDatos.add(lectura);

                    }

                    Intent i = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("cadena", arregloDatos);
                    startActivity(i);
                }catch (Exception g)
                    {
                        Toast msg =Toast.makeText(this,g.getClass().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        msg.show();
                    }

                break;
            }
```

Edit: i find the problem, the problem is the cursor, becose i comment it and the app not show any exception.
now...my problem is "how to read data from SQliteDatabase object"

Comment: Are you sure the path to your database is correct?

Comment: yes, y read it from Toast and got "/storage/emulated/0" and check the file exists fom my file explorer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are able to write SQLDatabases to external. If it is all string or int data, you could write the Database to internal, then write a function that will iterate through the table and concatenate the data and write it to external as a .txt.

Yep, just read the documentation on the .openDatabase method. I think the first param is looking for the path portion of the content URI, not an ext memory file path.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase(java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int,%20android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)

Comment: you say i can't open database from my phone memory and my sdcard?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can write one there. I think the Android framework is setup to put sql databases in app allocated internal storage. But you could get the cursor and use a while loop (cursor.movetonext()) and concate the database info and then write it to a .Txt file in external storage.